# jQuery: AddClass every second

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery waypoint trigger and I need to add a new class to the same element every second a set number of times. How I can I set a timer like function in jQuery?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of classes and some element, lets call it `<div id="myEl"></div>`, you can do the following:

```
var $el      = $('div#myEl'),
    classes  = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'],
    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
      if (classes.length === 0)
        window.clearInterval(interval);

      $el.addClass(classes.shift());
    }, 1000);
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CKjAf/1/)**

The key is to use `window.setInterval(fn, interval)`, which accepts a callback function `fn` that is executed every `interval` milliseconds. You'll notice that I've added a conditional line here for when the `classes` array is empty.

Basically, the `window.setInterval` function returns a unique integer id which corresponds to the new interval that you have instantiated. To cancel the interval (assuming you don't want it to run forever), simply pass this id to the `window.clearInterval` function. In this case, I want to cancel the interval loop when I have added all of the classes in the `classes` array.